# Creating a Bland-Altman plot for data in two columns in data frame

Tags: r, data-visualization

I have a data frame `data_2` and wish to create a Bland-Altman plot to compare the differences between the data in the columns `alog1` vs. `dig1`. 
Please help with the function for this and how to execute this. Would the function be `barplot()`?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: From wikipedia `with(data_2, plot(.5*{alog1+dig1}, alog1-dig1))`

Comment: ok, how would I be able to insert the arguments xlab,ylab and main in order to label the axes and the plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another name for a [Bland-Altman plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bland%E2%80%93Altman_plot) is a *Tukey mean-difference plot*.  (I have nothing against Bland and Altman, but I think 'mean-difference' is more descriptive.)  Note that this different from a [boxplot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boxplot) (observe the pictures on the two Wikipedia pages).  The mean-difference plot is simply a regular scatterplot, except that instead of plotting `x` versus `y`, you are plotting the difference `x-y` against the mean of `x` and `y` (or in your case, `alog1` and `dig1`).  Probably the easiest way to make this is to form these two new variables first, and then simply plot them as you would any other scatterplot.  Here is some sample code:

```
mn  <- (data_2$alog1 + data_2$dig1)/2
dif <-  data_2$alog1 - data_2$dig1
plot(mn, dif)
```

If you wanted to add arguments to customize your plot, you could do that just as you normally would, for example:

```
plot(mn, dif, main="Bland-Altman plot", xlab="mean of alog1 & dig1", 
     ylab="difference between alog1 & dig1")
```

Comment: ok, how would I be able to insert the arguments xlab,ylab and main in order to label the axes and the plot?

Comment: Bland has written (somewhere) that when he and Altman first presented the approach at a conference, they expected to be told that this was not original and that it was called X. But no one said that.